# How to open ngbDatepicker on click of input

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to open bootstrap 4 date picker on the click of input field.
i don't want to display calender icon
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<input
  readonly
  placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
  class="form-control"
  ngbDatepicker 
  (click)="datePicker.toggle()"
  #datePicker="ngbDatepicker">
```

I created a small demo example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anhgsg

Comment: I have tried your example, it is working but I have to click 2 times to close the calender

Comment: what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: I want to call one function based on selected date.

Comment: Also, what I want is to open calender on clicking of input and close the calender after selecting the date.

Answer (score 2):

Give   click function  `(click)="d.toggle()"`  to input field instead of giving to calendar icon

Comment: what will be the event of selecting the date?